# How to change mac app name from executable?

Tags: macos, dock, .app

I have a mac app.  Let's say the app is myapp.app, and runs an executable called myapp.  In the docker, when you hover over the icon, it says 'myapp'.  I would like to change this so that the hover over says something different, such as My App.

This isn't a question how to do it once I'm on the mac, but how to build the app in such a way that this is the default behavior.  I am constructing the .app on a Linux machine.  Is this something that can be set in Info.plist or similar?

(I'm specifically wanting to have the display name have a whitespace in it, as it is two words, else I would change the executable name itself)

Comment: `<key>CFBundleName</key>
 <string>Sublime Text</string>` probably.

Comment: @Rishav, no, the Dock doesn't use the bundle name from the Info.plist. It used the name of the app bundle in the file system.

Comment: @ffConundrums: Having whitespace in the name (the bundle filename or the executable) is no problem. The executable name doesn't matter for the Dock, though.

Comment: @KenThomases thanks so much, I didn't realize I could keep a space in the executable.  Just change the executable name (Info.plist to update that), and the name of the app itself - worked like a charm :)  (Well, with followup to the app code of course)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, Dock uses file system name. So you should change .app name to "My App.app"